# Put query parameters in collapsable menus in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

In my FastAPI application I have a number of endpoints, each with about 20 query parameters that I am **generating automatically**. I am setting the parameters using the `openapi_extra` option in the endpoint:

```
@app.get("/COLORS/", openapi_extra=generate_params(schemas.COLORS))
async def colors( request: Request ):
    return handle_request( # stuff that is not relevant #)
```

When the FastAPI server is started this will generate something that looks like:

[image]

What I would like to do is put the `RED_`, `GREEN_`, and `BLUE_` parameters into their own little collapsable menus if possible so that the docs will look cleaner. Is this possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370808/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131490/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

Modify openapi's "schema" of each parameter in your `generate_params` function. For reference you can declare Pydantic model, that suits your shape,  and inspect its schema (i.e. Color.schema())

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, can you give an example of a schema that would produce collapsable menus under an endpoint?

Comment: @JaredDuPont {'title': 'Help', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'email': {'title': 'Email', 'type': 'string'}, 'color': {'$ref': '#/definitions/Color'}}, 'required': ['email', 'color'], 'definitions': {'Color': {'title': 'Color', 'description': 'An enumeration.', 'enum': ['RED', 'BLUE']}}}

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for adding a choiceable dropdown menu in openapi as query parameters like an existing enum?

If so here's an example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/send-invoice")
async def send_invoice(
    priority: str = Query("normal", enum=["normal", "high"])
) -> dict:
        return {"result": priority}
```

[image]