# How to define query parameters using Pydantic model in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

I am trying to have an endpoint like `/services?status=New`

`status` is going to be either  `New` or `Old`

Here is my code:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from enum import Enum

router = APIRouter()

class ServiceStatusEnum(str, Enum):
    new = "New"
    old = "Old"


class ServiceStatusQueryParam(BaseModel):
    status: ServiceStatusEnum


@router.get("/services")
def get_services(
  status: ServiceStatusQueryParam = Query(..., title="Services", description="my desc"),
):
    pass #my code for handling this route.....
```

The result is that I get an error that seems to be relevant to this issue [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/884)

The error says `AssertionError: Param: status can only be a request body, using Body()`

---

Then I found another solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67581078/11065874).

So, my code will be like this:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from enum import Enum

router = APIRouter()

class ServiceStatusEnum(str, Enum):
    new = "New"
    old = "Old"


class ServicesQueryParam(BaseModel):
    status: ServiceStatusEnum


@router.get("/services")
def get_services(
  q: ServicesQueryParam = Depends(),
):
    pass #my code for handling this route.....
```

It is working (and I don't understand why) - but the question is how and where do I add the description and title?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `ServiceStatusQueryParam`. Why not just annotate the `status` parameter of your route directly with `ServiceStatusEnum`. That will work. Do you _really_ need an entire JSON object in a URL query parameter? Seems super cringe to me.

Comment: I dont clearly understand the difference bc I am new to fastapi but you seem right. I tested and it is working

Comment: The way you had it in your first code snippet, the URL query parameter would _theoretically_ have to be `?status={"status":"New"}` or something to that effect because you set the type of the `status` query parameter to be your `ServiceStatusQueryParam` model, which in turn serializes to a JSON object. Whereas you just want your query to be `?status=New`, so essentially of type string, but constrained to the enum members.

Comment: what if I wanted to do some validation on the string? how would I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To create a Pydantic model and use it to define query parameters, you would need to use [`Depends()`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) along with the parameter in your endpoint. To add `description`, `title`, etc., to query parameters, you could wrap the `Query()` in a `Field()`.

It should also be noted that one could use the `Literal` type instead of `Enum`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370808/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73401333/17865804). Additionally, if one would like to define a `List` field inside a Pydantic model and use it as a query parameter, they would either need to implement this in a separate dependency class, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067473/17865804), or again wrap the `Query()` in a `Field()`, as shown below.

Moreover, to perform validation on query parameters inside a Pydnatic model, one could do this as usual using Pydantic's [`@validator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/), as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73151350/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003724/17865804). **Note** that in this case, where the `BaseModel` is used for query parameters, raising `ValueError` would cause an `Internal Server Error`. Hence, you should instead raise an [`HTTPException`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/nl/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-httpexception) when a validation fails, or use a custom exception handler, in order to handle `ValueError` exceptions, as shown in Option 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75545471). Besides `@validator`, one could also have additional validations for `Query` parameters, as described in [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/) (see [`Query` class implementation](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/6ce6c8954cf0bf526cc605e8f5eb1e3f2b95c675/fastapi/params.py#L105) as well).

As a side note, regarding defining optional parameters, the example below uses the [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) type hint (accompanied by `None` as the default value in `Query`) from the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module; however, you may also would like to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804), which describe all the available ways on how to do that.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator
from typing import List, Optional, Literal
from enum import Enum

app = FastAPI()

class Status(str, Enum):
    new = 'New'
    old = 'Old'


class ServiceStatus(BaseModel):
    status: Optional[Status] = Field (Query(..., description='Select service status'))
    msg: Optional[str] = Field (Query(None, description='Type something'))
    choice: Literal['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] = Field (Query(..., description='Choose something'))
    comments: List[str] = Field (Query(..., description='Add some comments'))
    
    @validator('choice')
    def check_choice(cls, v):
        if v == 'b': 
             raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail='Wrong choice')
        return v

@app.get('/status')
def main(status: ServiceStatus = Depends()):
    return status
```

##### Update

Please note that in Pydantic V2, `@validator` has been deprecated and was replaced by `@field_validator`. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) for more details and examples.

Comment: can you read the comment on the original question?

Comment: and could I include Path here as well and run complex validation between the fields?

Comment: suppose I wanted a certain combination of status and comments. how could I do the validation?

Comment: thanks. you are right. actually I have already taken two courses on udemy about fastapi but still I sometimes dont know what a developer is supposed to do and not supposed to do. I can create endpoint but cant understand is this what professionals are doing or not and is this sth the creators of fastapi would imagine a developer doing or not

Comment: for example, now that you provided this example, I am wondering if I should include `Path` and `Body` in the `ServiceStatus` class as well or not

Comment: if we had `services/{service_id}`, would you add `service_id: str = Field (Path(..., description=''))` under`class ServiceStatus(BaseModel)` as well or not?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72068032/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74536449/17865804) (you may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72815364/17865804) helpful as well). Please make sure to read the linked answers above, as well as any references included, thoroughly.

Comment: What if I wanted to make the status choices case-insensitive?

Comment: To future readers: To make `enum` values case insensitive, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131490/17865804)

Comment: Omg this has wasted so much of my time... Thought it was a much more complicated bug and couldn't figure it out. Thanks for posting this!